# Почему заедает анимация?

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь реализовать анимированый скролл блока от `left: 0;` до `right: 0;`.

Первый запуск (клик по `left` кнопке --> клик по `right` кнопке) отрабатывает нормально, а вот повторный (повторный клик по `left` кнопке) вызывает резкий скачок.

Что не так со скриптом?

```js
$('.left').on('click', function(){
  
  $('.scroll-box').animate({
    right: '0px'    
  }, 1500, "linear", function(){
    $('.scroll-box').css({'left': 'auto'});
  });
});

$('.right').on('click', function(){
  
  $('.scroll-box').animate({
    left: '0px'    
  }, 1500, "linear", function(){
    $('.scroll-box').css({'right': 'auto'});
  });
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

.scroll-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
}

.ctrl {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: tomato;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="scroll-box">
    <span class="ctrl left"> l </span>
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="http://themastercleanse.org/wp-content/uploads/mc-article-graphic-inserts-1000x250-mode-selection.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <span class="ctrl right"> r </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вернуть css свойства к первоначальному варианту после выполнения второй анимации:

```js
$('.left').on('click', function(){
  
  $('.scroll-box').animate({
    right: '0px'    
  }, 1500, "linear", function(){
    $('.scroll-box').css({'left': 'auto'});
  });
});

$('.right').on('click', function(){
  
  $('.scroll-box').animate({
    left: '0px'    
  }, 1500, "linear", function(){
    $('.scroll-box').css({'right': '', 'left': ''});
  });
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

.scroll-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
}

.ctrl {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: tomato;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="scroll-box">
    <span class="ctrl left"> l </span>
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="http://themastercleanse.org/wp-content/uploads/mc-article-graphic-inserts-1000x250-mode-selection.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <span class="ctrl right"> r </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо!